# Ubuntu software center don't find programs

Tags: 16.04, software-center

I use Ubuntu 16.04.4 x64 and have a problem with Ubuntu software center. It doesn't find some programs (for example teamviewer) even more: software center doesn't find any program that's already installed

[image: programs]

Comment: How did you install teamviewer? Using a PPA that was added to Ubuntu? Or from command line using dpkg? If the latter the answer should be obvious: Ubuntu software center only knows about installed software using Ubuntu software center.

Comment: I mean what i can't install teamviewer from software center, like i do it before. And I mean what default programs just like firefox or others dosen't display in software center.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Software Center: `sudo apt-get remove software-center --purge`. Then re-install it: `sudo apt-get install software-center`. You now should find a new-look Software Center that works OK. You will find it from File Manager in Computer/usr/share/applications, where you can drag the icon to the Launcher Bar.

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done`
`Building dependency tree `      
`Reading state information... Done`
`Package 'software-center' is not installed, so not removed`
`The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm5.0`
`Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.`
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: Looks like it's already uninstalled then. Run `sudo apt-get autoremove`, and reboot. Is the SC icon still showing on your Launcher Bar?

Comment: Yes it still on Launcher bar

Comment: I removed Software center `sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-software`, and installed it again,  but nothing changed. Even more, I change in System settings > Software & update Server from  Ukrainian to Main server.

Comment: But you said that SC would **not** remove after my initial answer, as Ubuntu said it was not installed when you tried to remove it. If that icon does not disappear after you remove SC then there is possible system corruption.

What do you see when you run `dpkg -l | grep software-center`?

Comment: `rc  software-center                             16.01+16.04.20160420                         all          Utility for browsing, installing, and removing software
ii  software-center-aptdaemon-plugins           0.1.6build1                                  all          The aptdaemon plugins for software-center
`

Comment: OK. So SC is installed. So if you now run `sudo apt-get remove software-center` does it remove it?

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'software-center' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apt-xapian-index gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 libxapian-1.3-5 oneconf oneconf-common
  python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-attr python-blinker
   ...
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: OK. Out of interest if you go to */usr/share/applications*, is SC shown in there? I've tried uninstalling and re-installing SC several times on my 16.04 system and have no issues. On your system Ubuntu is contradicting itself, so likely system corruption here. I would try one more *apt-get autoremove*, reboot, then one more *apt-get remove*. If it still fails then I would recommend a re-install to save time trying different things. Make sure you back-up your home directory and data first.

Comment: I think it something  about last updates, because I installed Ubuntu 16.04.4 on virtualbox and update it. After update Ubuntu Software work like I  wrote before. But in Xubuntu 16.04.4 I haven't problem like this.